# Why can't we make a motor using the torque on a dipole in an electric field?

Tags: electrostatics

My textbook(halliday) talks about torque and potential energy of a dipole placed in an electric field. 
[image]

It doesn't say anything about its applications. I'm pretty sure there must exist some practical limitations. Theoretically it seems plausible that we can make the dipole spin continuously by switching the direction of external electric field. I'd like to know why this torque cannot be used to do mechanical work. Thanks!

Comment: Would the downvoter kindly let me know why so that it helps post a better question next time ?

Comment: -1 Not useful as a physics question. Nobody is claiming that this cannot do mechanical work. You are asking for applications, which is an engineering question.

Comment: I see how this is an engineering question and not physics. Ty for responding :) I should delete the question ? @sammygerbil

Comment: I think this is definitely a Physics question. The first electric motors were made by physicists when electrical engineers did not exist yet.  See History of the Electric Motor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_electric_motor Furthermore, Physics comprises also the field of Applied Physics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applied_physics .

Comment: @freecharly While physics *enables* good engineering, and engineering could be colloquially described as "applied physics," the question still isn't about the underlying physical concept but about how to power a machine with it.

Comment: @Asher - Even when you ask how to make a motor using  the torque on a dipole, this is a physics question. Applied Physics is part of Physics, even when some unworldly physicist deem it  beneath their dignity to think of applications.  Maybe some of those should have a look, for example,  at the thriving American Institute of Physics  publications Journal of Applied Physics and Applied Physics Letters, or at the American Physical Society publication Physical Review Applied. See https://www.aip.org and https://www.aps.org .

Comment: @freecharly in the meantime, you could take a look at the site rules here, where engineering questions are explicitly defined as off-topic for the site.

Comment: @Asher - Then I recommend you to lead by example and erase all your answers here that have a possible connection to applications.

Comment: Hey I've been on this site for a few years and I can clearly see how both of you are correct in your own ways. It hurts to see two awesome physicists waste time because of my stupid question. May be just flag it and let a moderator do the dirty job of deciding the fate of this question :)

Answer (score 5):

It can and this kind of thing is used in MEMS micromechanical technology. The magnetic force on a current is a much more practical effect for electromechanical work production. One doesn't have to accumulate nett unbalanced charges on the rotor and the figures turn out to be much more practicable. It is only when the motor is very tiny and the torque needed very small that electrostatic motors become practicable. Also, the electromagnetic motor can use a split ring commutator to switch the field direction; there is no analogue for electric field. These days, however, with all kinds of technology to sense the rotor's angular position available, this last is a minor point.

You should calculate the torque you would get for practicable electric fields and charges and compare these with the Lorentz force on currents from practicable magnetic fields. That exercise more than any answer will show you the reasons for the lack of use of the idea aside from specialist fields, such as MEMS microactuation.

Comment: Ahh ty :) I guess its not that east to put together lots of charge as they repel and also there is a limit on max electric field due to electric breakdown. I'll look up MEMS. Seems very interesting...

Comment: @rsadhvika MEMS in general are extremely interesting IMO.  Maybe it's just because I'm a sucker for how "futuristic" they seem compared to other common electronics.

Answer (score 1):

Electrostatic motors have been demonstrated since the 1700s (1st by Andrew Gordon and Benjamin Franklin). However, they usually need high voltages and are much more cumbersome to use than magnetic motors. See [Wikipedia Electrostatic motors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_motor).